# lazy evaluation of variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, lazy-evaluation

I have a config as such:

```
hierarchy = {
    // all different Geos
    State: {
        'dataSource'  : $scope.stateData,
        'class'       : 'stateContainer',
        'fillColor'   : 'red',
        'stroke-width': 2
    },
    County: {
        'dataSource'  : $scope.countyData,
        'class'       : 'countyContainer',
        'fillColor'   : 'green',
        'stroke-width': 1
    }
    // same for zip3, zip5 etc...
    // config options list shortened for simplicity
};
```

Then, there is the drawing function, a single function that takes the name of what I want to draw (State or County or ...), as shown below in pseudocode:

```
function drawGeo(geoName) {
    /* pseudocode */

    // this is OK
    something.attr('class', hierarchy.geoName.class)

    // not OK
    var data = loadData(hierarchy.geoName.dataSource) 
}
```

The reason for using such config is to avoid having a separate function for drawing each geo (State ...), and to centralize all drawing configurations in one place (instead of managing function parameters all around the code and for each function call).

Given that `hierarchy.geoName.class` is a string, it causes no problem when being set.  The same for other constants such as `stroke-width`.

However, dataSource causes issue, mainly because `$scope.stateData` and `$scope.countyData` are undefined during the construction of the hierarchy config.

I was looking for some way of making those variable "lazy", and only fetch them when they are being accessed (as can be done in Scala and other languages).

One obvious strategy would be to enclose the variables in dataSource between quotes (so they become strings instead).  Then, fetch the actual content of the variable in the draw function using eval:

```
'dataSource'  : '$scope.stateData',
...

loadData(eval(hierarchy.geoName.dataSource))  // works
```

This will probably attract the **eval() = evil** army. So the question is:

1. given that the content of $scope.geoData is controlled, the eval's security concerns should not be a worry, right?  In which case, it should be safe to use eval() in this way?
2. are there other javascript ways to lazy fetch variables that would be considered less "evil"?
3. if "eval" is bad in this case, any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `eval` is evil here (mostly because it's slow, hard to debug, and the wrong tool). Why don't you use a simple function that you can call?

Comment: ahh i've seen your comments on various similar questions :) Would you please emphasize what you mean by "a simple function that you can call"?

Comment: Just make it `'dataSource': function() { return $scope.stateData }` and then `loadData(hierarchy.geoName.dataSource())` (or call it `getDataSource`, or just make it a getter property).

Comment: i see! that worked out pretty sweet, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Bergi's advice in the comments:

> eval is evil here (mostly because it's slow, hard to debug, and the
>   wrong tool)
>
> Instead, return it in a function such as:
>
> ```
> 'dataSource': function() { return $scope.stateData }
> ```
>
> Then, call it with:
>
> ```
> loadData(hierarchy.geoName.dataSource())
> ```